# PostgreSQL on MacOS

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, macos-monterey

I am new to programming on the macOS system, I just installed PostgreSQL via home-brew, however, when I attempt to make a local server, I get the following error:

> psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  could not open file "global/pg_filenode.map": Operation not permitted

I tried searching online, but other posts showed "file or directory not found" as opposed to Operation not permitted.

Comment: Throw it away and go to https://postgresapp.com ...

Comment: so uninstall it using home-brew?

Comment: I thought home-brew was good as a package manager

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark. Also any idea why Filburt removed my thank you at the end of my post?